# JQuery toggling checkboxes while clicking parent div

Tags: jquery

Here i'm having set of checkboxes with lables with in a div.checkbox

I want to toggle the checkboxes while clicking parent div.checkbox

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox" name="Data1" value="option1" />
  <label for="checkbox-1">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-2" type="checkbox" name="Data2" value="option2" />
  <label for="checkbox-2">CSS</label>
   <br /> 
    <input id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" name="Data3" value="option3" />
  <label for="checkbox-3">HTML</label>
  <br />
  <input id="checkbox-4" type="checkbox" name="Data4" value="option4" />
  <label for="checkbox-4">CSS</label>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
    var el = $('.checkbox input[type=checkbox]')
    if(el.is(':checked')){
          find(el).removeAttr('checked');
    }
    else {
        el.attr('checked','checked');
    }
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/2/)

How can i do this, please can any one help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set the checked property value

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', function(){
        return !this.checked;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SReKX/)

Comment: if i'm having multiple div's then?

Comment: @NareshKamireddy `$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').length;`

Comment: please can you make fiddle

Comment: it's making the checkbox behave weirdly when clicked on checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find) to limit the scope to the clicked element:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function(){
    $(this).find(":checkbox").prop('checked', function(){
        return !this.checked;
    });
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/LvdFs/).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  var el = $('.checkbox input[type=checkbox]')
```

to

```
  var el = $(this)
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNmhL/3/)

Answer (score 0):

It should add another event handling to trigger "checkbox" itself being click:

```
$(document).on('click','.checkbox input[type=checkbox]', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```